# Getting malformed output from Netsuite Rest API

Tags: curl, netsuite, rest

I am accessing NetSuite Rest API, but sometimes the API is getting Bad Request (for example user entering wrong values), in this case, the body returns malformed.

when I tested the URL and the same values and headers with Postman, it shows the BadReuest Body correctly, but the same thing in cUrl is returning gibberish results.
it happens only with (400)BadRequests.

this is what I got from Postman:

```json
{
    "type": "https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "o:errorDetails": [
        {
            "detail": "Invalid value for the resource or sub-resource field 'eid'. Provide a valid value.",
            "o:errorUrl": "/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryItem/eid:1111111130/price",
            "o:errorCode": "INVALID_ID"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is what I got from cUrl:
[image]

ps:

1. I know I can get this result from suiteQL or check for product existence first, but I am interested in how to get this data in the correct way.
2. the application accessing NetSuite Rest API is written by ASP.NET Core 3.1 and I get the same results as cUrl and it is malformed.

Comment: looks like a content-type header problem, are you expressing the expected content type?

Comment: yes @Josh, although this is a get method and for the Accept, also yes. I tried every possible header NetSuite provide. such as `application/vnd.oracle.resource+json; type=collection` and singular and error as well. could it be the data coming as stream?

Comment: another guess is charset, try charset utf-8, e.g. `application/json; charset=utf-8` or something like that

Comment: thanks @Josh, I tried that. I tried any possible encoding. ASCII, iso.even I got the bytes and tried multiple different Encodings and no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My team also ran into a similar issue while using the Netsuite REST API with .NET Core 3.1 (malformed error messages on Bad Request). We verified that the response coming back from Postman was not malformed (as you mentioned above). From there, we were able to determine that the error response coming back from Netsuite is gzipped, which Postman handles automatically. We added the following code to our .NET project to get things working:

```
public class GzipUtils
{
        public void CopyTo(Stream src, Stream dest)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[4096];
            int cnt;

            while ((cnt = src.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                dest.Write(bytes, 0, cnt);
            }
        }

        public string Unzip(byte[] bytes)
        {
            using var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            using var mso = new MemoryStream();
            using var gs = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress);

            CopyTo(gs, mso);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mso.ToArray());
        }
}
```

```
    public static class NetsuiteResponseTranslationUtils
    {
        public static NetsuiteError ToNetsuiteError(this HttpResponseMessage response, ICompressionUtils compressionUtils = null)
        {
            var errorContent = string.Empty;

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode && response.Content != null)
            {
                var bytes = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

                if (compressionUtils == null)
                {
                    compressionUtils = new GzipUtils();
                }

                errorContent = compressionUtils.Unzip(bytes)
                    .Replace("o:errorCode", "errorCode")
                    .Replace("o:errorDetails", "errorDetails");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorContent))
            {
                return null;
            }

            try
            {
                var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NetsuiteError>(errorContent);
                return error;
            }
            catch
            {
                return new NetsuiteError
                {
                    Title = "Unparsable Error Content"
                };
            }
        }
}
```